# How do I manage changes to child records when the Parent has a Temporal key?

Tags: sql, orm, temporal

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  id    INT,
  start DATETIME,
  end   DATETIME,
  addy  TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, start, end)
);
```

This is tied to an ORM model for storing updates in Temporal terms, so instead of `UPDATE`ing, you create a new record with the same `id` and new `start`/`end` dates.

Okay, so now if I have a (temporal) child record of `accounts` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
  id INT,
  start DATETIME,
  end   DATETIME,
  amt   DECIMAL(6,2)
)
```

How do I distinguish between Invoices which *should* reflect the changes to the parent Account, and those which do not?

For example:

```
Accounts
id  start  end   addy
1   d0     null  123 Main St

Invoices
id    act    start    end     amt
1     1      d0       null    100
```

The invoice obviously relates to the Account record at 123 Main St.

```
Accounts
id  start  end   addy
1   d0     d1    123 Main St
1   d1     null  234 First St

Invoices
id    act    start    end     amt
1     1      d0       null    100
```

Now, what will be the value of `Invoice.Account.addy`? 123 or 234?

Do I need additional fields to help determine which one? If so, what will those column(s) look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Temporal records generally have a two part unique key: the part that you would normally think of as the key and the timestamp. In this case, "id" + "start". I'm not clear on what is desired here. There are a number of questions: why is account even "updated"? will "id" + "start" be unique? is an end required? PeopleSoft uses effective dated records. Perhaps the [tutorial](http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/effective-dates-sequence-status) gives hints on how to proceed.

Comment: Account is updated IRL when someone gets better information about an account, usually phone numbers but sometimes addresses. The composite id+start+end will be unique, and be the pkey. This is because Invoices are assigned to an Account, but as the account existed at a certain Time.